# When fetching all mail boxes of gmail getting this warning

Tags: php, imap

```
Notice:  Unknown: [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: [Gmail] (Failure) (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

no idea why I am getting this notice.
I used

```
$mbox=imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", $username, $password);
$list = imap_getmailboxes($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "*");
```

to fetch all gmail folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send a `LIST` command to list all mailboxes, the entry for `[Gmail]` says:

```
* LIST (\HasChildren \Noselect) "/" "[Gmail]"
```

That is, this mailbox cannot be selected (`\Noselect`).

I'd guess that `imap_getmailboxes` doesn't care about the `\Noselect` flag and tries to select that mailbox anyway.

Comment: Thanks very much @legoscia it works just as i need. The change i made as you said is.                                                                                              $list = imap_list($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "*");